# htaccess language based virtual subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Good nigh,
Im trying to create virtual subfolders for user's browser language.

So i have the following folder structure:

```
www/
    Core/
        Classes/
            Autoloader.Class.php
            Smarty.Class.php
            Database.Class.php
            LoadingOrder.json
        Libraries/
            Smarty.Class.BC.php
            Smarty.Class.php
            SmartyModules/
                ..
        Modules/
            Autoloader.Module.php
            Wall.Module.php
            Account.Module.php
            LoadingOrder.json
        Engine.php
        Initialize.php
    Templates/
        Default/
            css/
                main.css
                style.css
                ErrorHandler.css
            images/
            javascript/
                jquery.js
            Main.tpl
            User.tpl
            ErrorHandler.tpl
    .htaccess
    index.php
    user.php
    ErrorHandler.php
```

The thing i need, is to create multilingual website.

**For example:**
User want to go to his/her page: `http://site.domain/user`

The thing i want to implement, is that based on his browser language, it will redirect him to
`http://site.domain/en/user` - if he speaks English,
`http://site.domain/ru/user` - if he speaks Russian,
`http://site.domain/pt/user` - if he speaks Portugese.

The thing is, these language subfolders should be only virtual, and the all their requests should be made to only user.php, which is one in the root directory.

I've been googleing, and found that on http://battle.net - there is kind of system like this.

So is it possible to create system like this via htaccess, or its purely php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(user)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will redirect `/user` to `/en/user` in browser but will load `/user.php?lang=en` silently.

Comment: That almost solved my problem, but still when i try to enter `/user` it redirects me to `/en//user`

Comment: Made a correction to remove `//` and make it `/en/user`

Comment: thx alot, corrected it using  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]